# Force per unit area on a solenoid

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations, electromagnetic-induction

I am having a hard time attempting to eliminate constants of integration while solving maxwell's equations. Here is an example of a solenoid. Let a wire carrying current $I$ wind $n$ times per unit length of a cylinder on a cylinder with axis along the $z$ axis. We can treat it as surface current $\def\p{\hat{\boldsymbol\varphi}} \def\r{\hat{\boldsymbol\rho}} \def\z{\hat{\boldsymbol z}} K\p$, where $K=In$.

I am trying to find the magnetic force per unit area on the cylinder. Let me work in cylindrical coordinates. Inside and outside the solenoid, we have $\def\B{\mathbf B}\nabla\times\B=0$, so
$$
\left(
    \frac{1}{\rho} \frac{\partial B_z}{\partial \varphi}
  - \frac{\partial B_\varphi}{\partial z}
  \right) \hat{\boldsymbol \rho} \\
+ \left(
    \frac{\partial B_\rho}{\partial z}
  - \frac{\partial B_z}{\partial \rho}
  \right) \hat{\boldsymbol \varphi} \\
{}+ \frac{1}{\rho} \left(
    \frac{\partial \left(\rho B_\varphi\right)}{\partial \rho}
  - \frac{\partial B_\rho}{\partial \varphi}
  \right) \hat{\mathbf z}=\mathbf 0
$$
I have to start arguing by symmetry. By symmetry, $\B$ should be independent of $z$, and $B_z$, $B_\phi$ and $B_\rho$ independent of $\phi$, and  so we may remove some terms, which leads to:
$$
    \frac{\partial \left(\rho B_\varphi\right)}{\partial \rho}=0, \frac{\partial B_z}{\partial \rho}=0\\
\Rightarrow \B=\frac{C_1}{\rho} \p+ C_2 \z+ C_3 (\rho) \r
 $$
Also, 
$$
 {1 \over \rho}{\partial \left( \rho B_\rho  \right) \over \partial \rho}
+ {1 \over \rho}{\partial B_\varphi \over \partial \varphi}
+ {\partial B_z \over \partial z}=0,\\
$$
$$
{\partial \left( \rho B_\rho  \right) \over \partial \rho}=0, \\
\Rightarrow \B=\frac{C_1}{\rho} \p+ C_2 \z+ \frac{C_3}{\rho} \r
$$
**Now I get stuck.** What should I do to eliminate those arbitrary constants? I am willing to accept that **inside the cylinder**, by symmetry, $B_\rho, B_\phi=0$ at the axis of the cylinder, so $C_1=C_3=0$. But what about $C_2$?

I know that any value of $C_2$ is valid (imagine an offset due to the magnetic field of the earth). I also know that by boundary conditions, $C_2$ should differ by $\mu_0 K$ across the boundary. The force experienced by the cylinder is the force due to the **average** of magnetic field on both sides of the cylinder, so when $C_2=0$, this average has magnitude $\frac{\mu_0K}{2}$, and from this, we can work out the force per unit area on the cylinder.

**But why should I have $C_2=0$? What value of $C_2$ most closely resemble real-world solenoids?** I have no clue.

If we do have $C_2=0$, the solenoid is going to expand under this force - which could possibly result in oscillations of its radius. This sounds crazy. Can we really observe it in the lab?

**EDIT:** by integration, I find that **it is actually the case that the $\B$ field just outside the solenoid is zero.** This is very surprising to me. How can I understand this intuitively?